# Not able to access the application running in wsl when connected to VPN

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am running a simple python rest server in port 3000 in wsl2 ubuntu machine and not able to access this using wsl ip address.

- http://localhost:3000 works with and without vpn
- http://172.x.x.x:3000 (wsl ip) works without vpn

http://172.x.x.x:3000 not working with vpn

Comment: Have the same problem. I've seen some issues open for cases like this. Looks like WSL2 can't correctly port when using a VPN.